# Windows 7 "Family Pack" licenses

Tags: windows-7, license

Microsoft has provided a 3 license "Family Pack" for Windows 7.  The description specifies that it is for 3 computers in one household.  How specific is this restriction.  Is Microsoft actually checking this, or should we all be running out, purchasing the 3 packs, and reselling the licenses for $80 each?

Comment: If you aren't going to follow the license agreement, then you might as well go find a crack online for $0.  Why would anyone pay for an illegal copy?

Comment: People pay for illegal copies of things all the time.  Haven't you ever seen anyone selling bootleg movies?  Ethics aside, my question is about the license agreement.  Is this 'one household' thing a requirement in the license agreement, or just a marketing term?  Would it be a violation, and if it is, is compliance enforced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this site: [SuperSite.com](http://community.winsupersite.com/blogs/paul/archive/2009/10/26/confirmed-windows-7-family-pack-disc-is-identical-to-upgrade-media.aspx)

The family pack is a mere licensing item rather than physical disk difference. In other words, the family three pack DVD is the SAME as a regular DVD found in the single license copy.

Essentially - you are allowed to activate the product on three different machines with the same code.

Comment: Yes, I found that site with Google too.  Anyone have any additional information?